# Convert .gsm to .wav with sox

Tags: codecs, convert, sox, wav

I'm trying to convert one music files with format `.gsm` to format `.wav`. This is how I tried:

```
for f in *.gsm; do sox $f new/${f%.wav}; done
```

The result is that I get the same files with the same format `.gsm` in the `new/` directory.

Can anyone point what the problem is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${f%.wav}` removes `.wav` from the end of the variable. Since `f` only ever contains filenames with `.gsm` at the end, `${f%.wav}` outputs the filename unchanged.

You probably want `"${f%.gsm}.wav"` instead (assuming either (a) `sox` actually did convert the files and only the extension is incorrect or (b) `sox` uses the filenames to determine the conversion required, so fixing the filenames would fix the conversion).

Comment: Thanks for the help but if do it this way `${f%.gsm}.wav` I got files with both extensions, like `file.gsm.wav`, `file1.gsm.wav`.. etc

Comment: @S.I. huh, Try `#` instead of `%`. Either `#` removes a suffix and `%` a prefix, or vice versa. I always mix up those.

Comment: I've tried it and still both extensions are there.

Comment: @S.I. I cannot reproduce. `${f%.gsm}.wav` correctly replaces the extension for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really don't have an idea what was the problem. After a restart of the machine and tried again now is removed the `.gsm` correctly.